# Auto-delete files after they've been on the server for 14 days

Tags: linux, ftp, filesystems, find

We have a Linux FTP server that clients and project managers upload files onto to exchange files.  Unfortunately, nobody ever goes in and deletes anything when they're done with it.  I'm looking for an elegant way to auto-delete a file after two weeks.

I was thinking a cron job with this syntax I found online.  My question is what day will it consider day 0?  The day the file was created on the user's local machine, or the day it was copied to the Linux box?

```
find /path/to/directory/* -mtime +t -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your parameter to `find` is `-mtime` which translates to *"File's  data was last modified n*24 hours ago"* according to the [documentation for `find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find), it would be the date the file has been uploaded to (or modified on) your FTP server.

To determine a suitable value for `+t` take a look at the following section about how find rounds the time for matching:

> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file  was  last    accessed,
>   any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the -atime option instead of -mtime.  It will find based on the last time the file was accessed.

Comment: You might want to make sure your filesystem isn't mounted with noatime first.

Answer (score 1):

Also, check out [tmpwatch](https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/) or [tmpreaper](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/tmpreaper.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

find will use the mtime on linux box. Hopefully this is the host where FTP server is running.